# What is magical about Cartan's magic formula?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, math-history

Why is [Cartan's magic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#The_Lie_derivative_of_differential_forms)
$$\mathscr{L}_X\omega = i_Xd\omega + d(i_X\omega)$$

called "magic"?

Should it be considered a highly surprising result?  Does it "magically" prove several other theorems?  What is the etymology? (Why it is variously referred to as E.Cartan's formula and H.Cartan's formula?)

Comment: Well it spells out $\mathcal{L}_X$ in terms of contraction and the exterior derivative, it's very user-friendly. In particular you can establish easy results, for instance when $\omega$ is a closed symplectic form and $X$ is the Hamiltonian vector field.

Comment: Either one of the Cartans, [father Élie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Élie_Cartan) or [son Henri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Cartan) could plausibly have invented it... See also [the MO thread *Is “Cartan’s magic formula” due to Élie or Henri?*](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39540/is-cartans-magic-formula-due-to-lie-or-henri)

Comment: Yes, I've seen the MO thread, in fact.  The parenthetical question at the end of the post is not mine, but was added by others.

Comment: Maybe because $\mathscr{L}_X$ is of $0$-degree (derivation) and is nicely related to a $1$-degree map $d$ and a $-1$-degree map $i_X$

Answer (score 20):

I would have liked to put this as a comment but I do not have enough points to do it.

I think there is some magic in this formula because it tells us that the Lie derivative $\mathscr{L}_X$ is homotopic to zero with the homotopy $i_X$ going from top-right $\Omega^{p+1}(M)$ to bottom-left $\Omega^p(M)$ diagonally in the following diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\cdots @>{d}>> \Omega^p(M) @>{d}>> \Omega^{p+1}(M) @>{d}>> \cdots \\
\qquad @V{\mathscr{L}_X}V{0}V @V{\mathscr{L}_X}V{0}V\\
\cdots @>{d}>> \Omega^p(M) @>{d}>> \Omega^{p+1}(M) @>{d}>> \cdots
\end{CD}$$