# Show $k$-form/chain identity

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, derivatives

Let $\omega$ be a closed $k$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $c:I^k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ a $k$-cube on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with flow $\Phi_t$. Show that $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_c\Phi_t^*\omega=\int_{\Phi_t\circ\partial c}i_{\mathbb{X}}\omega$$ where for a ($k-1$)-chain $\mathcal{C}=\sum_ra_rc_r$, the ($k-1$)-chain $\Phi_t\circ \mathcal{C}$ is defined to be $\sum_ra_r(\Phi_t\circ c_r)$

I don't know where to start, I cannot see the first step I should take.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Formulas to use:

$L_\mathbb{X}\omega=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0}\Phi_t^*\omega=i_\mathbb{X}d\omega+di_\mathbb{X}\omega$

$\int_cd\omega=\int_{I^k}c^*d\omega$

I still havn't been able to make much progress, could someone verify: is it correct to say that the right will have one more integral from $0$ to $1$ than the left or the other way around? $c$ a $k$-cube, whereas $\partial c$ is a $(k+1)$-cube or $(k-1)$-cube, which one?

---

**Progress**: I have realized that the question mentions some subtle information which I had been previously overlooking.

"$\omega$ a closed $k$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$"

A differential $k$-form $\omega$ is closed if $d\omega=0$

This means that in the equation of the Lie derivative $i_\mathbb{X}d\omega=0$

Therefore we have

$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0}\Phi_t^*\omega=di_\mathbb{X}\omega$

This looks remarkably similar to what I am trying to prove, any hints as to what I should do next would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you need is the Cartan's formula: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507753/cartans-magic-formula

Comment: @John: I am familiar with this formula, I have tried rearranging $L_\mathbb{X}\omega$ formula to make some progress, but cant see the steps to simplify either side to the equation. If you were to have another look it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$
\begin{aligned}{d\over dt}\int_c \Phi_t^* \omega &= \int_{\Phi_t\circ c} \left.{\partial \over \partial t}\right|_{t=0}\Phi_t^* \omega
\\ &= \int_{\Phi_t\circ c} \mathcal{L}_\mathbb{X}\omega
\\ &= \int_{\Phi_t\circ c} \iota_\mathbb{X} \underbrace{d \omega}_{=0} + d \iota_\mathbb{X} \omega~\text{(by Cartan's Formula)}
\\ &= \int_{\underbrace{\partial(\Phi_t\circ c)}_{=\Phi_t\circ \partial c}} \iota_\mathbb{X} \omega~\text{(by Stokes' Theorem)}
\end{aligned}
$$