# 2 -form invariant under the flow of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields, pullback

I have this exercise.

Let $(x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3)$ be coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and let
$$ w = dx_0 \wedge dx_1 + dx_2 \wedge dx_3 $$.
Let  $u: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function and $X$ be the following vector field:
$$
X = -\partial_1(u)\partial_0 +\partial_0(u)\partial_1 -\partial_3(u)\partial_3 +\partial_2(u)\partial_3
$$

Show that if $\phi_t^X$ defines the flow of X and $\phi_1^X$ is defined, then $(\phi_1^X)^* w = w.$

[Hint: Consider $\frac{d}{dt}(\phi_t^X)^* w$]

Comment: Can you show us how you arrived at the constant solution?

Comment: What is $c_t$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Um.... it's not clear how $\partial_1 u  = 1$. You know nothing about the function $u$. Back to your question, you need to calculate $\frac{d}{dt} (\phi^X)^*$, so explicit form of $\phi^X$ is not needed.

Comment: yes I think I was wrongly trying to compute the flow explictly, but as you said I cannot do it and I do not need to do it. Can I ask you how would you attack the problem ? basically how can I compute $\frac{d}{dt}(\phi^X)^{*}$ without the explicit form of the flow.

Comment: It will be just a two line proof if you know [Cartan's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507753/cartans-magic-formula?noredirect=1&lq=1) and that $du = \iota_X \omega$.

Comment: Perhaps you could fix the title a little bit. Something like "$2$-form invariant under the flow of a vector field"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
Define $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^4$ to be the solution of $\gamma' = X(\gamma)$ and $\gamma(0) = p \in \mathbb{R}^4$. The flow you want to compute is $\varphi_t^X(p) = \gamma(t)$.

Write $\gamma = (x_0(t),x_1(t),x_2(t),x_4(t))$ in coordinates and find the differential equations verified by the coordinates. For example, for the first and second coordinate:
\begin{align}
{x_0}'(t) &= -\partial_1u(x_0(t),x_1(t),x_2(t),x_3(t))\\ {x_1}'(t) &= \partial_0 u(x_0(t),x_1(t),x_2(t),x_3(t))
\end{align}

*Remark* it appears constant are not integral curves of the vector field if $\partial u$ is not zero.

**Edit** To answer the (new) question there is no need to compute the flow, but just to use its definition. By the very definition of the Lie derivative of a differential form in the direction of a vector field, one has
\begin{align}
\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}\varphi^*_t\omega = \mathcal{L}_X\omega
\end{align}
By the Cartan's (magic) formula,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_X\omega = \mathrm{d}\left(\omega(X,\cdot)\right) + \mathrm{d}\omega\left(X,\cdot\right)
\end{align}
As $\mathrm{d}\omega = 0$ (easy computation), it is
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_X\omega = \mathrm{d}\left(\omega(X,\cdot)\right)
\end{align}
But
\begin{align}
\omega(X,\cdot) &= -\partial_0u\mathrm{d}x^0 -\partial_1u\mathrm{d}x^1-\partial_2u\mathrm{d}x^2-\partial_3u\mathrm{d}x^3 \\
&= -\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}
and thus
\begin{align}
\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}\varphi^*_t\omega = \mathrm{d}\left(-\mathrm{d}u\right) = -\mathrm{d}^2u = 0
\end{align}
and consequently, $\varphi_t^*\omega$ is constant. As $\varphi_0 = \mathrm{id}$, it is equal to $\omega$.

Comment: @120548 I edited the answer to highlight the dependency of the differential equation with $t$. Without any asumption on $u$ we cannot say much about the general form of $x_i(t)$ I guess.

Comment: @120548 I edited my answer to give a concrete answer to your (new) question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !!! I have just one doubt, in the exercise I have to show the invariance w.r.t.  the flow $\phi_1^X$. Can I still apply your reasoning ?

Comment: @120548 The fact that $\varphi^*_t\omega$ is constant show that it is the same at $t=0$ and $t=1$, and at $t=0$ it is $\omega$, so $\varphi_1^*\omega = \omega$